# Relationship between logistic regression and Softmax Regression with 2 classes

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification, softmax

Suppose we have data matrix $X$ which is $n\times p$ matrix ($n$ data points, and $p$ features including intercept), i.e., we already add the intercept term (append $1$ column) to $X$

- For logistic regression (binary classification), the model parameters / regression coefficients $\beta$ is a length $p$ vector.
- For softmax regression (multi-class classification), the model parameters $W$ is $p \times m$ matrix, where $m$ is the number of classes.

Now, suppose we set $m=2$, then $W$ is a $p \times 2$ matrix. They are the same model, so the number of parameters CANNOT be doubled and we should be able to derive one from another.

So, my question is

**What is the relationship between $\beta$ and $W$?**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Suppose you have a binary classification problem with $p$ features (including bias) and you do Multi-class regression with softmax activation. Then, the probability of an observation, $x,$ representing class $1$ is,

$$
\begin{split}
p_1(x) &= \frac{\exp(\beta_1^T x)}{\exp(\beta_1^T x) + \exp(\beta_2^T x)} \\
&= \frac{1}{1 + \exp[(\beta_2 - \beta_1)^T x]} = \sigma\left([\beta_1 - \beta_2]^T x\right).
\end{split}
$$
where both $\beta_1$ and $\beta_2$ are $p \times 1$ parameters, and I simply multiplied both numerator and denominator by $\exp(- \beta_1^T x).$ Note that the RHS of the above expression is simply the sigmoid function. Thus, the $p \times 1$ parameter $\beta$ you would get from doing ordinary binary logistic regression with sigmoid activation is analogous to $\beta_1 - \beta_2,$ where the latter parameters are from multiclass softmax regression.

Answer (score 8):

In [multinomial regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression) we model odds of observing $Y=k$ for each of the $K-1$ classes relatively to the $K$-th class. So with $K=2$ the model reduces to logistic regression.

Let me quote [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression):

> One fairly simple way to arrive at the multinomial logit model is to
>   imagine, for $K$ possible outcomes, running $K-1$ independent
>   binary logistic regression models, in which one outcome is chosen as a
>   "pivot" and then the other $K-1$ outcomes are separately regressed
>   against the pivot outcome. This would proceed as follows, if outcome
>   $K$ (the last outcome) is chosen as the pivot:
>
> $$ \begin{align} \ln \frac{\Pr(Y_i=1)}{\Pr(Y_i=K)} &=
>  \boldsymbol\beta_1 \cdot \mathbf{X}_i \\ \ln
>  \frac{\Pr(Y_i=2)}{\Pr(Y_i=K)} &= \boldsymbol\beta_2 \cdot \mathbf{X}_i
>  \\ \cdots & \cdots \\ \ln \frac{\Pr(Y_i=K-1)}{\Pr(Y_i=K)} &=
>  \boldsymbol\beta_{K-1} \cdot \mathbf{X}_i \\ \end{align} $$
>
> (...) Using the fact that all $K$ of the probabilities must sum to
>   one, we find:
>
> $$ \Pr(Y_i=K) = 1 - \sum_{k=1}^{K-1}{\Pr(Y_i=K)}e^{\boldsymbol\beta_k
>  \cdot \mathbf{X}_i} \Rightarrow \Pr(Y_i=K) = \frac{1}{1 +
>  \sum_{k=1}^{K-1} e^{\boldsymbol\beta_k \cdot \mathbf{X}_i}} $$
>
> We can use this to find the other probabilities:
>
> $$ \begin{align} \Pr(Y_i=1) &= \frac{e^{\boldsymbol\beta_1 \cdot
>  \mathbf{X}_i}}{1 + \sum_{k=1}^{K-1} e^{\boldsymbol\beta_k \cdot
>  \mathbf{X}_i}} \\ \Pr(Y_i=2) &= \frac{e^{\boldsymbol\beta_2 \cdot
>  \mathbf{X}_i}}{1 + \sum_{k=1}^{K-1} e^{\boldsymbol\beta_k \cdot
>  \mathbf{X}_i}} \\ \cdots & \cdots \\ \Pr(Y_i=K-1) &=
>  \frac{e^{\boldsymbol\beta_{K-1} \cdot \mathbf{X}_i}}{1 +
>  \sum_{k=1}^{K-1} e^{\boldsymbol\beta_k \cdot \mathbf{X}_i}} \\
>  \end{align} $$

With [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) you have only

$$
\ln \frac{\Pr(Y_i=1)}{\Pr(Y_i=0)} =
 \boldsymbol\beta \cdot \mathbf{X}_i
$$

and probabilities derived from it. Logistic regression and multinomial regression with $K=2$ **are the same thing**.

### Example

If you take the data from [this online tutorial](https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/) and run logistic regression and multinomial regression on it, you'll see exactly the same results (compare the coefficients):

```r
library(nnet)
mydata <- read.csv("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/binary.csv")
mydata$admit2 <- ifelse(mydata$admit == 1, 0, 1)
## 
## glm(admit ~ gre + gpa, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
## 
## Call:  glm(formula = admit ~ gre + gpa, family = "binomial", data = mydata)
## 
## Coefficients:
## (Intercept)          gre          gpa  
##   -4.949378     0.002691     0.754687  
## 
## Degrees of Freedom: 399 Total (i.e. Null);  397 Residual
## Null Deviance:       500 
## Residual Deviance: 480.3     AIC: 486.3

multinom(cbind(admit2, admit) ~ gre + gpa, data = mydata, family = "binomial")
## 
## # weights:  8 (3 variable)
## initial  value 277.258872 
## final  value 240.171991 
## converged
## Call:
## multinom(formula = cbind(admit2, admit) ~ gre + gpa, data = mydata, 
##     family = "binomial")
## 
## Coefficients:
##       (Intercept)         gre       gpa
## admit   -4.949375 0.002690691 0.7546848
## 
## Residual Deviance: 480.344 
## AIC: 486.344
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but i think it did not answer my question. I know they are the same, and trying to ask how to derive $\beta$ from $W$.

Comment: @hxd1011 but they are the same thing, so you don't have to derive anything...